# How to insert a static block above recently compared/ recently viewed blocks?

Tags: magento

I want to insert a static block above the recently viewed/ recently compared products block in the product catalog page. Even with after="-", it inserts the block below these blocks.
Any pointers?? I would not want to change the catalog.xml because this static block could be different for different category catalog pages. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In layouts `after` means below so you probably want `before="-"` instead.

Comment: Thanks! It worked .. I had actually tried it but didn't refresh the layout cache so it didn'r reflect earlier.